# How to resolve error when overriding mssql-jdbc driver in Classpath - Main method not found in class

Tags: java, classpath

I want my java application to use jdbc 7.4.1 version. After researching, I found overriding classpath is one way to do it. But I am getting below error.

Environment: RHEL

override classpath

```
java -cp /home/xyz/sqljdbc_7.4/enu/mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

Error

```
Error: Main method not found in class com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application
```

Question:
Is this the right way to do it or there are other/better ways to accomplish the same thing?
Secondly, how to resolve the error I am getting?

Answer (score 1):

With the line

```
java -cp /home/xyz/sqljdbc_7.4/enu/mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

you are executing the class 
`com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver` with class path set to `/home/xyz/sqljdbc_7.4/enu/mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar` That's the reason why you getting the error given above. Because jvm tries to find the main entry point (public static void main()) in the jar com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver. I guess you want to set both jars in class path and execute your own programm. The you have to call it that way:

```
java -cp .:/home/xyz/sqljdbc_7.4/enu/mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar:com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver <place your jarfile here>
```

Comment: Why is it complaining when executing the class com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver with class path set to /home/xyz/sqljdbc_7.4/enu/mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar ?

Comment: Because com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver doesn't have the method ```public static void main(String[] args)``` You want to use the Driver and not execute the class ```com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver```

Comment: Is there another way to default all jobs to use jdbc-7.4.1 instead of doing 
```java -cp .:/home/xyz/sqljdbc_7.4/enu/mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar:com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver <place your jarfile here>```

I want all my Talend jobs to use that driver